# Calling Ruby function from C++ in a loop results in "stack level too deep"

Tags: c++, ruby

I'm trying to run blocks of Ruby code from C++. I have two Ruby functions, one called Init(), and one called Loop(). The problem I have is that I can only Loop() so many times before I get a "stack level too deep" from SystemStackError. My Ruby code is not recursive as far as I can tell. As you can see, so far this Ruby code is just for a proof-of-concept and loaded with nothing but debug-style stuff and blinking a light on a panel. Here's the Ruby code:

```
def Init()
    puts 'Hello from script\'s Init()!'
    $i = 0
    $p = Panel.new
    $p.Debug
    $p.Extinguish( "Running" )
    $p.Illuminate( "Fault" )
end

def Loop()
    puts 'Hello from Loop!' + $i.to_s
    $i += 1
    puts $p
    $p.Debug
    $p.Illuminate( "Running" ) if $i % 2 == 1
    $p.Extinguish( "Running" ) if $i % 2 != 1
end
```

My implementation of Panel in C++ is:

```
ruby_init();
VALUE cPanel;
cPanel = rb_define_class( "Panel", rb_cObject );
rb_define_singleton_method( cPanel, "new", (RubyMethod*)&StaticRubyNew, 0 );
rb_define_method( cPanel, "Debug", (RubyMethod*)&StaticRubyDebug, 0 );
rb_define_method( cPanel, "Extinguish", (RubyMethod*)&StaticRubyExtinguish, 1 );
rb_define_method( cPanel, "Illuminate", (RubyMethod*)&StaticRubyIlluminate, 1 );
```

I call the script functions as follows:

```
rb_eval_string( program );

rb_funcall( Qnil, rb_intern( "Init" ), 0, NULL );

// In a 200ms loop:
rb_funcall( Qnil, rb_intern( "Loop" ), 0, NULL );
```

Nothing worked until I wrote a (suspect) implementation of **new**:

```
VALUE MainWidget::RubyNew( VALUE clas )
{
    // Looks like we have to return *something* instead of Qnil, even if I
    // don't have anything to wrap yet.
    const char* s = "Dude";
    VALUE tdata = Data_Wrap_Struct( clas, StaticRubyMark, StaticRubyFree, const_cast<char*>(s) );
    return tdata;
}
```

RubyMark and RubyFree don't do anything, and RubyDebug, RubyIlluminate, etc. don't do anything remarkable either for the problem at hand.

I've tried wrapping Init and Loop in a class as class methods, so I can call rb_funcall() with a real receiver. I've tried getting a backtrace by calling through rb_protect() (the backtrace appears empty). Nothing online seems to have the secret for loading the script as a string, so rb_eval_string() is a guess. rb_load_file() doesn't work either.

Why does this cause stack problems? I can edit my Ruby script, adding or removing code, and the stack blows after executing various numbers of loops. The number of loops that I can execute has no discernible relationship to the number of lines. If I remove a line, I might get 45 loops. If I remove another, I might get over 2000. What am I doing wrong?

A little more code in light of the response below--this is to give C++ methods to Ruby API calls (which expect C-style functions):

```
typedef VALUE (RubyMethod)(...);
extern "C" /*static*/ VALUE StaticRubyNew( VALUE self )
{
    return MainWidget::M_this->RubyNew( self );
}
```

Comment: Well I'm a little closer--I pulled all this out into a purely C driven app and it runs for at least 500,000 loops (before I killed it). It must be something I'm doing wrong with a C++ to C interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I pared it down until I got a working version similar to my C implementation but the problem has nothing to do with C++ vs C. What's not shown above (because I didn't think it was relevant) is that this is a Qt application, and I have two slots--one to initialize ruby and load the program, and another to call the loop function. The latter slot is called repeatedly from a timer (not relevant). The breakthrough happened when I moved ruby_init() out of the slot and into main(). A search on Google revealed this interesting [answer](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/149451):

From Matz himself, "No Ruby object should be referred from stack region lower than the
position at the time of ruby_init() invocation."

So what's happening is that when each slot is called, they're at an indeterminate place on the stack, while if you call ruby_init() from main() and then start running Qt's event loop, you'll definitely be in the right place on the stack to do rb_funcall() etc.

Comment: Incidentally, does anybody know why Ruby has this rule? Why is stack position relative to other calls so important? How do you even write code that's dependent on stack position relative to other calls (remember that ruby_init() returns before rb_funcall is called, so they shouldn't be on the stack at the same time)?

Comment: A little later down in the thread you reference: "Ruby needs to know the size and location of the stack so the GC can mark objects on the stack." and "Ruby needs to know the location of the C stack so it can be marked, otherwise extensions would break." Are they intermingling the C stack with the Ruby stack? This strikes me as a needless attempt at cleverness and possibly false laziness.